# Spring LDAP ADLDS user permission for changing password/ password policy issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-ldap

When using Spring LDAP template to change a password it is currently using the below code sample

```
Attribute attr = new BasicAttribute("userPassword", newPassword);
ModificationItem item = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, attr);
ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(dn, new ModificationItem[] {item});
```

We are currently using a admin user to establish connection with LDAP and that is able to change the password for the users. Even though we have a password policy set in ADLDS to prevent users from setting last 12 passwords we are still able to change. What is the permission that I can set in ADLDS or spring code to achieve the above functionality?

Comment: You may have to use Fine Grained Password Policy on your AD server, however this is not related to 'LDAP' or 'spring-ldap' but to AD administration.

Comment: So this is (or not) related to the user access like we have Admin login which has lots of privileges that replaces the password for other users. So if the fine grain password policy is implemented and even if we use admin user to change the password, old password will be verified and error message is return if we use the previous password?

Comment: I'm not an AD expert, but other LDAP implementations allow to specify that an 'adminstrative user' is not allow to bypass the password policy. Hopefully AD provides similar feature.

Sidenote: Actually a password change (different to password reset) should be done by deleting the old password value and adding the new value). For this the 'userpassword' attribute is marked as 'multi-valued' in the RFC. Ideally it's performed by binding with the actual user instead of a 'technical user'.